# Regular Expression to match an exact word with any number of spaces before and after it

Tags: regex, qregexp

I want to find an exact word "SUBRECORD" with any number of spaces before and after it. I have tried:

```
\s*SUBRECORD\s*
[ ]*SUBRECORD[ ]*
(\s)*SUBRECORD(\s)*
```

but none of them work.

EDIT:

this is the snippet of code that's not working:

```
QStringList list;
list.append("RECORD \"DEFSTA\" \"Definition des Stations\"");
list.append("  STRING     (2)  \"Version\";");
list.append("  SUBRECORD   (2)  \"Nb de Stations\";");
list.append("    STRING    (30) \"Nom de la Station\";  ");
list.append("    INTEGER   (2)  \"Numero de la Station\";");
list.append("    INTEGER   (4)  \"Extra charge\";");
list.append("    STRING    (5)  \"Mnemonique Station\";");
list.append("    DUMMY     (1)  \"Réserve\";");
list.append("  ENDSUBRECORD;");
list.append("  SIGNATURE        \"Signature\" ;  ");
list.append("ENDRECORD;");

qDebug() << "LAST INDEX OF SUBRECORD:" << list.lastIndexOf(QRegExp("\\s*SUBRECORD\\s*"));
```

Comment: What kind of text are you searching through? [Those regex look correct.](http://regexr.com?376c7)

Comment: I'm reading a text file line by line and then in a line i want to see if the word "SUBRECORD" exists. a line can look like this: `  SUBRECORD   (2)  "Nb de Parametres";`

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I meant are you using `c++`, etc..?

Comment: Yes I'm using C++ and Qt libraries.

Comment: Post your code you have tried so far.

Comment: if i put `QRegExp(".*SUBRECORD.*")` it returns the index of last appearance of "ENDSUBRECORD;" which would be 8 here.

Comment: @MoKi your last comment would suggest that your regex is correct but the lastIndexOf is matching on the full line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason:**

`lastIndexOf(...)` only returns the index if there is an exact match of the entire line. This is from the Qt docs:

> `int QStringList::lastIndexOf ( const QRegExp & rx, int from = -1 ) const`
>
> *Returns the index position of the last **exact match** of rx in the list, searching backward from index position from. If from is -1 (the default), the search starts at the last item. Returns -1 if no item matched.*

Because `\s*SUBRECORD\s*` does not match the line exactly, it does not count it as a match.

---

**Solution:**

Instead try: `.*\\s+SUBRECORD\\s+.*`

The extra `.*` matches anything extra at the beginning and end.

The `\s+` ensures there is at least one space (thanks @T.V.) - also, the extra `\` is to escape the backslash when inputting as a QString (thanks @MoKi).

Comment: The solution you suggested would result in the index of `ENDSUBRECORD;` being return.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to \s+ so that it looks for at least one space character

Comment: the correct form would be to use double escape characters that is `.*\\s+SUBRECORD\\s+.*` since Qt accepts `QString` as the `QRegExp` constructor's argument. and yes you are right about it matching the whole line.